# Change degree of x-axis labels without changing color?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, rpy2

I have a script that produces the following graph:

[image]

It is as simple as:

```
p = ggplot2.ggplot(nb_islands_df) +
    ggplot2.aes_string(y='times_seen', x='other_timepoint') +
    ggplot2.geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    ggplot2.facet_grid(ro.Formula('nb_timepoints ~ main_island')) 
    + ggplot2.theme(**{"axis.text.x": ggplot2.element_text(angle=90, vjust=1)})
```

All is working as I'd like it to, except for one thing: when I change the angle of the text, it also changes color of the x-axis text to black.

How do I get the original color back or avoid changing the color in the first place? I know I can add a color option to the last line above, but what color should I put there.

If there are several answers, I will accept the one that explains why this happens. But I assume it is just a bug.

Comment: If it's a bug, it might be a bug in rpy2, because I can't reproduce that behavior directly in R.

Comment: @baptiste I thought they were claiming that simply adding `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust = 1))` was actually _causing_ a change of the color to black, which I don't see in R.

Comment: @baptiste: that sounds like an answer to me. Set colour to "grey50". Make it a proper answer and I'll vote for it. Please also add the info about where can I find the source code snippet that says that?

Comment: @joran I agree, I jumped to a conclusion without testing. It works as intended, in R, I don't know what could cause a problem with python.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat `theme_grey` shows all the values that are being set for the default theme.

Comment: @joran: that was what happened with rpy2. Will update with version numbers on monday.